# Comparing datatable values between row for change detection

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable

My goal is to detect & write information which value changed before we update row to database.

For example, I have two datatables with same column structure: `beforeEdit` and `afterEdit`. In this case, I only have one row for each datatables.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To beforeEdit.Columns.Count - 1
    If beforeEdit(0).Item(i) <> afterEdit(0).Item(i) Then
        'storing log which column have changed
    End If
Next
```

Is there any better approach to do this task?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two `DataTables`.  Each `DataRow` already maintains two copies of the data.  The `RowState` property of a `DataRow` can tell you whether it has changed or not.  It will be `Unchanged` if no change has occurred and `Modified` otherwise.  You can use code like this to determine if and what changes have occurred in a `DataRow`:

```
Private Sub LogRecordChanges(row As DataRow)
    If row.RowState = DataRowState.Unchanged Then
        Console.WriteLine("No changes to row.")
    Else
        For Each column As DataColumn In row.Table.Columns
            Dim currentValue = row(column, DataRowVersion.Current)
            Dim originalValue = row(column, DataRowVersion.Original)

            If currentValue.Equals(originalValue) Then
                Console.WriteLine($"No changes to column '{column.ColumnName}'.")
            Else
                Console.WriteLine($"Column '{column.ColumnName}' changed from '{originalValue}' to '{currentValue}'.")
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```